How can I execute a command whenever I change the PowerDevil power profile?
I have a laptop with a variable refresh rate (up to 120Hz) monitor. I want to change the refresh rate to 60 whenever I switch the power profile to "Power Save" in Powerdevil, and change it to 120 whenever I switch the profile to Performance. I already have two shell scripts prepared, refreshRate60.sh and refreshRate120.sh, which require root privileges.
How can I execute these scripts whenever I change the power profile in PowerDevil?
I'm using Kubuntu 23.10.

How do you switch the profile? Wouldn't it be easier to use the scripts instead and add PowerDevil profile changing to them?
